# RPi-compatible online backup service

Tags: backup, file-server

I would like to use my RPi partly as a home file-server.  I'm currently using a desktop for the same task.  For instance, all of my family's pictures and home videos are on the file-server; but only a fraction of them are ever on the laptop.  I currently use some custom rsync scripts to sync new data from the laptop to the file-server.

I've decided it's time to pay for an online backup service in order to get off-site storage of our most irreplaceable data (home videos, pictures, etc.).

I'd like to give my RPi the job of file-server (via USB hub and HDD enclosures) and have it deal with syncing to an online backup service.  However, I'm having a really hard time finding any online backup service that explicitly supports the Raspberry Pi.

I've seen some examples of getting crashplan to run; but that's it.

Does anyone know of any online backup services that provide official support for RPi?  What about other services that people have successfully gotten to run?

**Edit for further clarification:**
Raspberry Pi uses an ARM processor.  Most services that do provide a Linux client only provide a client for the x86 or x86_64 architecture and not ARM.  So official support for a Linux client on the ARM architecture is what I'm ideally looking for.

**Edit:**
I received a response from SpiderOak, they do not currently have any plans for supporting Raspberry Pi.  But this is a company that actually has official support for the N900, so it might not be hard to convince them to support the RPi if a few more people ask them about it.  I particularly like that they store the backups in a way that prevents themselves from seeing the data.

Comment: Why do you feel you need an "online backup service that explicitly supports the Raspberry Pi"?  Surely anything that can communicate over Ethernet is viable?

Comment: I intend to use the RPi as my local file server and I want it to be able to sync to an online backup service.  It will be the only local location with a complete set of files to backup.  So I need a service that can run its client on the RPi to handle the automated syncing.  Honestly, I could live with a service that lets me just use rsync, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Googling for rsync backup service will find some options. Also you could look at tarsnap. It uses an open source client so you may be able to compile it on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: related: [Portable system for syncing files (like DropBox)?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1066/3763) Maybe [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) (basically an automated `git`-on-change) plus a simple file hoster does the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Found this script which is supposed to provide unofficial support for CrashPlan on the Raspberry Pi: http://pastebin.com/K3xGa28g

**Edit:**
Here are some more related resources that would probably be useful for using CrashPlan on the RPi:

These first 2 come from this thread: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5398

This script was used to successfully install CrashPlan on the RPi
http://geekfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/crashplan.sh_.txt

This post describes installing CrashPlan on another ARM device (PogoPlug):
http://www.opticality.com/blog/2011/07/16/installing-crashplan-on-a-pogoplug-pro/

--

This post describes getting CrashPlan installed on a headless (no display) Linux server (but does not address the ARM architecture issue):
http://www.liquidstate.net/blog/technology/installing-crashplan-on-a-headless-linux-server/

And this post describes using the CrashPlan GUI on another computer to connect to and manage the CrashPlan instance running on the headless server:
http://www.liquidstate.net/blog/technology/how-to-manage-your-crashplan-server-remotely/

Answer (score 1):

You could try ownCloud which you can host yourself and is incredibly easy to set-up.
There are some useful walk throughs and semi automated scripts to set-it all up.

With very little effort you can have it running on Nginx.
https://www.google.de/search?q=owncloud+rapsberry+pi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

You could then send your pi(or a 2nd Pi) off to these guys, who will add pop it into their datacenter for free: http://raspberrycolocation.com/

Seems like the perfect solution to me, and the only cost would be the cost of posting your rPi to them.

Answer (score 1):

IDrive has linux scripts which work on rpi. The scripts use the QNAP NAS (ARM) binaries, which happen to work well. These scripts can also be used to set up scheduled backups

Answer (score 1):

To make up an RPi-compatible backup service, I can advise you to install CrashPlan on Raspberry Pi. For that (as CrashPlan works only on x86 Linux) you need to use some Linux environment emulator to be set up and switched on as a first step. Below, I'm gonna get you a tutorial, with ExaGear Desktop emulator, as an example. On your side, you can use any type of a an emulator ;)

**Set up ExaGear Desktop**

1. Put ExaGear Desktop archive with installation packages and ExaGear Desktop license key in the same folder. Open Terminal (command line), move to this folder and unpack the archive using the following command:
   $ tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi*.tar.gz
2. Install and activate ExaGear by running install-exagear.sh script:
   $ sudo ./install-exagear.sh
   Launch guest x86 system
3. Enter the guest x86 system using the following command:
   $ exagear
   Starting the shell in the guest image /opt/exagear/images/debian-8
   Check that you’re in x86 environment by running the ‘arch’ command:
   $ arch
   i686
4. It is recommended to update apt-get repositories on the first launch of the guest system:
   $ sudo apt-get update

**Install CrashPlan**

5. Remember! It is super important for you to download specific libraries to enable CrashPlan browser operations. Simply input:
   $ sudo apt-get install lxrandr libgtk2.0-0 libXtst6 cpio
6. Now, you have to get back to the folder, where CrashPlan archive has been previously downloaded. Usually, it is the “Download” folder if you’re using a Raspberry Pi model. In case of Raspberry Pi, the path to the folder that you should input into the command line is the following:
   $ cd /home/pi/Downloads
7. As soon as you are inside this directory, unpack the files:
   $ tar -xvzpf CrashPlan_4.8.2_Linux.tgz
8. Install CrashPlan inside the x86 guest system. NOTE! Directory where we are operating in this tutorial is optional and valid only for Raspberry Pi hardware!
   $ cd /home/pi/Downloads/crashplan-install
   $ sudo ./install.sh

The installation manager will offer you to install a number of directories. Agree with all default options by pressing Enter to all the queries.
Configure CrashPlan autostart

9. To make CrashPlan service autostart after system reboot type the following commands:
   $ sudo service crashplan start 2>/dev/null
   $ sudo update-rc.d crashplan enable

**Run CrashPlan**

10. To start CrashPlan type the following command:
    $ /usr/local/bin/CrashPlanDesktop
    Otherwise you can run CrashPlan from the Start menu:

You’ll see a browser window with the empty fields to fill out and start up your account. Just go ahead and follow the form guide. After completing this registration you’ll start the backing up. So, enjoy[image: ![crashplan on raspberry pi]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdF8D.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use S3 from amazon web services, which has a storage gateway accessible in linux for slip streaming backups.